# React useEffect returns empty array after fetching data with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect, react-fullstack

I'm trying to fetch my data from an api I created, but it always returns an empty array.

Here's my code

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

  const getOrders = async () => {
    try {
      const access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
      let result = await axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/orders/open",
        headers: {
          access_token,
        },
      });
      setOrders(result.data);

      console.log(result.data);
      console.log(orders);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getOrders();
  }, []);
```

This is the console result from my browser
[image]

As you can see, result.data successfuly returns 2 objects inside of it, but after I add it on order state with setOrders(result.data), order is still empty.

I've also tested the API on Postman and there's no problem at all.
[image]

I've been doing get data with axios this way and this is my first time having this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **It's because Reactjs's [Batching State Update](https://medium.com/swlh/react-state-batch-update-b1b61bd28cd2) mechanism**

Your state update is asynchronously so it won't be updated until the function/event is finished.

Check for `console.log(orders)` right before your `return()` function.

Comment: ahh I see.. thanks for the article. I didn't know that before

Answer (score 1):

look like you do console.log before state update, try adding setTimeout or console.log outside function like this

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  // you can console.log here after state update
  console.log(orders)

  const getOrders = async () => {
    try {
      const access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
      let result = await axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/orders/open",
        headers: {
          access_token,
        },
      });
      setOrders(result.data);

  console.log(result.data);
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    // or wait for 100ms until orders state updated
    console.log(orders);
  }, 100);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getOrders();
  }, []);
```